# Как поменять кодировку в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, кодировка

Делаю локализацию для приложения и столкнулся с проблемой кодировки..

```
autoLoginLabel.setText(properties.getProperty("settings.auto.login"));
```

[image: JavaFX label]

Что делать? `System.getProperty("file.encoding");` возвращает UTF-8.
Кодировка файла со свойствами - UTF-8. 
Спасибо!

UPD: можно сделать так:

```
String name = properties.getProperty("settings.auto.login");   
autoLoginLabel.setText(new String(name.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
```

Но может можно иначе и проще

Comment: Property в отдельном файле? Если да то скорее всего он в этой кодировке сохранен. Конвертируйте с помощью Notepad++. С его же помощью можно узнать и кодировку.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев кодировка у файла UTF-8, как я и указал выше :)

Comment: просто сам изучают Java. Интересовался FX для курсовой. Поэтому интересны проблемы с ним возникающие. Просто вроде бы Вы конвертируете из ISO в UTF. А это может быть только в случае различия кодировок. А у Property нет потока чтения из файла, может там установлена такая?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев да, действительно, в документации написано, что поток Property.load работает с кодировкой ISO-8859-1

Comment: вот и ответ на Ваш вопрос. Можете создать свою копию этого класса с нужной кодировкой, но это уже наверное не совсем верно. И изменить кодировку потока нельзя?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев проблему решил, в ответе напишу как

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена, подгружаю Property немного иначе, было так

```
languageProps.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/localization/ru_RU.properties"));
```

Стало

```
final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/localization/ru_RU.properties"), "UTF-8");
languageProps.load(inputStreamReader);
```